# Browser generated combo boxes and other input fields look weird in OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, browser, drop-down-menu

Since the upgrade to OS X yosemite, some input fields in the browser look weird. For example, Apple added a blue (!!!!) arrow icon to select boxes. Apart from that, the line height for select boxes looks strange. I'm searching for a possibility to make input elements look a bit less crappy. Sorry that the question is so unspecific. I already tried playing around with CSS3's appearance property, but setting it to 'none' doesn't work correctly in all browsers (chrome, firefox, safari) which understand the property.

Has anyone had any success fixing this stupid issue?!

[Screenshot of input elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJe29.png)

Comment: try using a [reset css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue - please try the mixing `@include appearance(none);` or just:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```